# Oracle DBA Role and its specific functions (and possible replacement)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, roles, privileges

I have to install an application server that requires an user to write to the database, possibly create new schemes and such. However, I've always used the "work around" to assign the DBA Role to that user.

I have some questions, as I am not that deep into Oracle security.

1. Has the DBA role a level of privileges that can affect the whole Oracle installation?
2. Where can I find what privileges the DBA role exactly have?
3. How do I create an alternative role?

Thanks,

Comment: What application server is so bad that it has to have SYSDBA to run?

Comment: @StephaniePage: The SYSDBA privilege is not a role, can not be assigned to a role, and is not part of the DBA role. OP is not talking about the SYSDBA privilege. Also, he clearly stated the functionality he needed; create schema's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Yes, the dba role should have enough privileges to screw up a database beyond fixing.

2)

```
select * 
  from role_sys_privs 
 where grantee = 'DBA';
```

3) Unless you plan on having several user with similar privileges, I recommend creating a user and grant all needed privileges explicitly to this user instead of via a role.

You can read more about the topic in
[Oracle Database Security Guide chapter 11, Administering User Privileges, Roles, and Profiles](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

First look into Ronnis' solution. If this is not sufficient create a package, owned by SYSTEM, and grant EXECUTE to the user or users that need it. Add procedures that perform the needed operations taking care to limit their power as much as possible.

Comment: If you don't like creating objects in SYSTEM then create a new user as Ronnis suggested and create the package there.